# Django deployment and virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am aware that there are many questions regarding Django and virtual environments, but I cannot wrap my head around the use of virtual environments with respect to deploying my Django app (locally) via uwsgi/nginx.

My setup includes a virtual environment (with Django and uwsgi), my Django app, nginx and PostgreSQL. The app was created before the virtual environment, and I applied only a single change to `manage.py`:

```
#!/Users/snafu/virtualdjango/bin/python3
```

When I start up the uwsgi located in the virtual environment (with the appropriate `.ini` file), everything works right away, but I wonder why. I did not need to fiddle around with the $PYTHONPATH, or append the site packages directory to the system path in `manage.py`, or activate the virtual environment at any point (apart from the initial installation of packages), although the boilerplate comment in `manage.py` explicitly mentions an inactive virtual environment as a possible reason for an import error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating a virtual environment does nothing but prepend the virtual environment's `bin/` to the `$PATH` thus making `python` and `pip` without explicit paths running from the virtual environment. Everything else related to virtual environments is implemented inside Python — it automatically changes `sys.path` and other paths (`sys.prefix`, `sys.exec_prefix`, etc).

This means that when you run `python` with an absolute path from a virtual environment Python automatically activates the virtual environment for this particular Python session. So you don't need to activate the virtual environment explicitly.

There is a minor warning sign on the road though: to run any Python script from a non-activated virtual environment you must set the shebang for all scripts to point to the virtual environment or use `sys.executable`. Do not use explicit `python` because that could be a different Python from the `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation is what I was looking for. Embarrassingly, I found it as an answer to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776580/470081) after asking my question.